# Use of “to” or “of”

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I just heard “the lyrics to the song” and I thought te correct way to say it is “the lyrics of the song”. Am I right? Otherwise, what’s the difference?
I’ve gotten this doubt because I’ve heard “to” instead of “of” expressing belonging in another sentences  and I couldn’t understand why that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both would be understood, but I tend to agree with you that it should be "the lyrics *of* the song". The lyrics are considered a part of the song, and as such are spoken of in the possessive, eg "*the song's lyrics*".

I suspect that the use of "*to*" comes from the fact that lyrics are words *set to* music. Historically, a lot of songs began as melodies only, and then words were put *to* them. As such "the words to the song" sounds quite idiomatic to my ears, but "lyrics *of* the song.

Answer (score 0):

One would say "dance to the music" and "walk to the beat" but "words of a book" so I think because music is often related to verbs you can use "to" or "of" in this case.